# java how can i loop the string until it reaches its length(strings)

Tags: java, string

```
String d="hello";
int length=10;// length is changable
```

I dont know how to loop 10 times this string "hello" on basis of its character.
It shows stringindex bound exception

Requried output:
h e l l o h e l l o h

Comment: show us what you have tried, and what errors you are getting.

Comment: You should read a basic tutorial.

Comment: I think your question is not completed.And your sentences are difficult to understand.Whatever....Use `int length = d.length();` to avoid exception about length.

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += "" + d.charAt(i % d.length());         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s="My String";
char[] c = s.toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.print(c[i]);
}
```

Java has a built-in function called `String.length()` use it to iterate and then print the value.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine with any given length.
Hope this helps.

```
    String str = "hello";
    int length = 10;
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    int len = chars.length;
    int temp = len;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {

        if (i > temp) {
            count++;
            temp = len * (count + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(chars[(i - (len * count)) - 1]);
    }
```